# How to build an FPGA based video filter?

Tags: fpga, video, hdmi

I have a computer that outputs a low-resolution (1280x720) image via DisplayPort. I want to take this image and, by programming an FPGA, apply an image processing algorithm that 'upscales' this image to 4K. I then want the output of the board to go via HDMI to a 4K TV set.

My questions:

- Is this at all possible?
- If it is, what dev board(s) would allow me to do this?
- Is it possible to get a better refresh rate out of the board? Reason I'm asking is that, currently, a direct DisplayPort-HDMI connection (via a converter, of course) gives me only 30Hz. Can we do better?

Thanks!

Comment: It is possible, but very, very difficult and not worth it.

Comment: @ilkhd explanation? alternatives?

Comment: Far cheaper, and a great deal quicker, to buy a new computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - Is this at all possible?

Sure, but you'll need a frame buffer in order to increase the frame rate. This would be in the form of external SDRAM, since few FPGAs have enough on-chip memory for a megapixel image (3 MB minimum).

The up-scaling in resolution is relatively easy, since 3840×2160 is exactly 3× the size of 1280×720 in each dimension.

You'll need a 3×3 (or perhaps larger) interpolation filter to eliminate the "jaggies" in the upscaled image.

> - If it is, what dev board(s) would allow me to do this?

That's a shopping question, which is off-topic here.

> - Is it possible to get a better refresh rate out of the board?

You can output each incoming frame more than once to get a simple frame rate increase, but if you want motion interpolation as well, that's much harder. You should Google "3D filter" to get an idea of what this involves. ("3D" refers to the combination of two spatial dimensions plus the time dimension.)

Comment: Finally, a readable answer instead of a downvote. Thanks!